# How do I edit the task in my to do list by doing a long press?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to create an edit function for updating a task that was previously written.

I have tried this so far but apparently the prompt is only for the browser. Would this even work? What are alternatives to create the prompt for react native?

```
  const taskUpdate = (index) => {
     const newItemsCopy = [...taskItems];
     const item = newItemsCopy[index];
     let newItem = prompt(`Update ${item.task}?`, item.task);
     let todoObj = { todo: newItem, complete: false };
     newItemsCopy.splice(index, 1, todoObj);
     if (newItem === null || newItem === "") {
      return;
      } else {
      item.task = newItem;
      }
      setTaskItems(newTodoItems);
  }
```

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/yaRejwUq)

Comment: Why do you need a prompt? Isn't the TextInput the prompt?

Comment: I want the user to long press the card within their list and upon the long hold, they would receive a prompt that allows them to update the task and submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this using [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal)

1. On long press, open the Modal which consists of textInput with value.
2. Edit the value.
3. Save the value on close/ handle it with save button inside Modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alert from react-native.

```html
import { Alert } from "react-native";

Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ]
    );
```